# Combining table column in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017

I have to combine the `Customer_address` when they have the same `address_index` but different `line_nbr`:

| CUSTOMER_NUM | CUSTOMER_CODE | CUSTOMER_ADDRSS | LINE_NBR | ADDRESS_INDEX | ADDRESS_CODE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 31 | GEW | 3901 Castle Hayne Road | 17 | 1 | SHIP |
| 30 | GEW | Highway 117 N | 18 | 1 | SHIP |
| 212 | GEW | 1005 2nd Street | 19 | 2 | SHIP |
| 23 | GEW | 3901 Castle Hayne Road | 20 | 3 | SHIP |
| 241 | GEW | Highway 117 N | 21 | 3 | SHIP |
| 360 | GEW | 465 McCarthy Road | 1 | 4 | SHIP |
| 469 | GEW | 3901 Castle Hayne Road | 1 | 5 | SHIP |
| 470 | GEW | Highway 117 N | 2 | 5 | SHIP |

I need to combine CUSTOMER_NUM 31 and 30 to read

```
Castle Hayne Road Highway 117 N
```

By combining `Address_index = 1` with `Line_nbr` 17 and 18, and also `Address_index = 3` with line_nbr 20 and 21, and Address_index 5 with line_nbr 1 and 2, etc....

New to SQL and trying to figure out how to link the two columns together and write out the customer address in one column instead of the two rows it currently resides.

Comment: Hey sorry SQL server 2017

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On SQL Server 2017+, `STRING_AGG()` makes this easy:

```
SELECT CUSTOMER_CODE, 
       MergedAddress = STRING_AGG(CUSTOMER_ADDRSS, ' ') 
                       WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY LINE_NBR)
  FROM dbo.MyTable
  GROUP BY CUSTOMER_CODE, ADDRESS_INDEX;
```

Output:

| CUSTOMER_CODE | MergedAddress |
| --- | --- |
| GEW | 3901 Castle Hayne Road Highway 117 N |
| GEW | 1005 2nd Street |
| GEW | 3901 Castle Hayne Road Highway 117 N |
| GEW | 465 McCarthy Road |
| GEW | 3901 Castle Hayne Road Highway 117 N |

On older versions, you're going to have to use more cumbersome and inefficient methods like this:

```
SELECT CUSTOMER_CODE, 
       MergedAddress = RTRIM((SELECT CUSTOMER_ADDRSS + ' '
         FROM dbo.MyTable AS inside
         WHERE inside.ADDRESS_INDEX = outside.ADDRESS_INDEX
         ORDER BY LINE_NBR
         FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value(N'./text()[1]', N'varchar(max)'))
  FROM dbo.MyTable AS outside 
  GROUP BY CUSTOMER_CODE, ADDRESS_INDEX;
```

The [example db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=694e2d950931f7e9fdb81bb9685199df) shows the results and also the plans that should help explain why the latter is so bad.

Comment: Thanks this was the answer